# consume rabbitmq messages hosted locally

Tags: rabbitmq

I have set-up a clustered local rabbitmq(cluster of 3 nodes) through docker. On the rabbitmq management UI, I am able to successfully create exchanges/queues, and publish messages.
My problem is, on the same UI I do not see the option to create any consumer, so my messages are published but do not show up in acknowledged or delivered state. 
Attached below is the screenshot for one of the queues, where you can see No Consumer.

[image]

I am new to rabbitmq so probably I have misunderstood the concept of consumer(or how to configure one)
Would really appreciate anyone suggesting how to configure the consumer to a queue through this UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is you cannot configure a consumer throw the Management UI. Consumer can be described as an application/client that receives and consumes message from certain queue. To consume message, you may need to write your own consumer code. Check [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) for more information. Hope this is helpful for you :)